# How to change scene based on button click using Unity and MRTK?

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I'm trying to implement a menu with some buttons in order to load different scenes based on the clicked button.

**What I've tried**
I created a total of 3 scenes : menu, main and secondary. The menu scene contains the buttons. On the first button I added `Interactable, NearInteractionTouchable and LoadContentScene`. I then selected the desired scene to load in `LoadContentScene` and added an `OnClick` event to the `Interactable` script which triggers `LoadContentScene.LoadContent`.
[you can see it there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Y3S9.png)

**The problem**
Now when I click on my button, the next scene isn't loading and I have those error messages in my Unity console :

> Unable to find ISceneTransitionService service.
> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
> Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Extensions.SceneTransitions.LoadContentScene.LoadContent () ...

What did I do wrong ? I tried to find some solutions in the documentation or online but I couldn't find any tutorials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error message you are trying to use the [Scene transition service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/mrtk2/features/extensions/scene-transition-service?view=mrtkunity-2022-05), please check if this service is registered in **MixedRealityToolkit->Extensions**. To clarify, for scene loading, this service is not necessary, if you don't know what it does, you can disable the corresponding code.

Also, you can refer [Scene system content loading - MRTK 2 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/mrtk2/features/scene-system/scene-system-content-loading?view=mrtkunity-2022-05) and this official sample - [OpenXR-Unity-MixedReality-Samples/BasicSample at main · microsoft/OpenXR-Unity-MixedReality-Samples · GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/OpenXR-Unity-MixedReality-Samples/tree/main/BasicSample).

Comment: It's already better but I keep getting `object reference not set to an instance of an object` when I try to load the scene. Here is a screenshot of my settings https://imgur.com/a/dAIenN1

Comment: Can you provide the code snippet for **LoadScene** and the screenshot of the **Scene System profile** in MixedRealityToolkit?

Comment: Following the `basic example` you linked, I set this Script to the button 1 (which gives the `object reference...` error ) :
`using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class SceneLoader : MonoBehaviour
{

    /// Request that the MRTK SceneSystem load a scene of a given name.
    public void LoadScene(string sceneName) => CoreServices.SceneSystem.LoadContent(sceneName, LoadSceneMode.Single);
}`
Button 2 is the same as my post https://imgur.com/a/ntP9Dbb

Comment: Here is the config of the Scene Manager : https://imgur.com/a/04LKlaH and now it works !